# Multiply two matrices (sumproduct for multiple functions) - to get Fishers discriminant linear function scores

Tags: r

I have a set of Fisher's discriminant linear functions that I need to multiply against some test data. Both data files are in the form of two matrices (variables lined up to match variable order), so I need to multiply them together.
Here is some example test data, which I've added a constant=1 variable (you'll see why when you we get to the coefficients)

```
testdata <- cbind(constant=1,mtcars[ 1:6 ,c("mpg","disp","hp")  ])
> testdata
                  constant  mpg disp  hp
Mazda RX4                1 21.0  160 110
Mazda RX4 Wag            1 21.0  160 110
Datsun 710               1 22.8  108  93
Hornet 4 Drive           1 21.4  258 110
Hornet Sportabout        1 18.7  360 175
Valiant                  1 18.1  225 105
```

Here are my coefficients matrix (the Fishers discriminant linear functions)

```
coefs <- data.frame(constant = c(-67.67, -59.46, -89.70),
                 mpg = c(4.01,3.49,3.69),
                 disp = c(0.14,0.15,0.22),
                 hp = c(0.13,0.15,0.20))
rownames(coefs) <- c("Function1","Function2","Function3")
> coefs
          constant  mpg disp   hp
Function1   -67.67 4.01 0.14 0.13
Function2   -59.46 3.49 0.15 0.15
Function3   -89.70 3.69 0.22 0.20
```

I need to multiply the values in test data against the respective coefficients to get 3 functions scores per row. Here is how the values would be calculated

```
for the first row, Function1 = 1*(-67.67)+21*(4.01)+160*(0.14)+110*(0.13)
for the first row, Function2 = 1*(-59.46)+21*(3.49)+160*(0.15)+110*(0.15)
for the first row, Function3 = 1*(-89.70)+21*(3.69)+160*(0.22)+110*(0.20)
```

It's kind of like a sumproduct of coefficients against each row time 3 for each function.
So the df/matrix should look like this when multiplied same number of rows with 3 function score variables

```
> df_result
                  Function1 Function2   Function3   
row1                53.24     54.33       44.99
row2
```

Not ideal, but I'm taking the data out doing it excel. If this is possible to do, any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for the inner product?

```
testdata <- cbind(constant=1,mtcars[ 1:6 ,c("mpg","disp","hp")  ])
coefs <- data.frame(constant = c(-67.67, -59.46, -89.70),
                    mpg = c(4.01,3.49,3.69),
                    disp = c(0.14,0.15,0.22),
                    hp = c(0.13,0.15,0.20))
rownames(coefs) <- c("Function1","Function2","Function3")

as.matrix(testdata) %*% t(as.matrix(coefs))
#                   Function1 Function2 Function3
# Mazda RX4            53.240    54.330    44.990
# Mazda RX4 Wag        53.240    54.330    44.990
# Datsun 710           50.968    50.262    36.792
# Hornet 4 Drive       68.564    70.426    68.026
# Hornet Sportabout    80.467    86.053    93.503
# Valiant              50.061    53.209    47.589
```